# Local Print PDFs silently from browser to a specific printers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, virtual-printer

I've got a web app that produces two different PDF. 
I need to print one to a printer named "A" and the other to printer named "B".
Those printers are not connected to the server.
Today users has to select printer every time. I need system know where to print every kind of pdf. 
How can I solve that?

Thanx

Comment: You can't and this is good like it is. I don't want, that arbitrary websites can use my devices without notice ;) Either the server can print itself, or the users have to be notified.

Comment: If your users are the employees of a company named "C", then just write and install a mini tool which prints two PDFs each to "A" and "B" printers.

Answer (score 1):

If you know Printer A and Printer B, you can get the SDK from the printer manufacturer and make them auto print.

Without knowing the printers you can not do this. If so every time you went to web page the owner would make your printer, print out advertisements. See why this is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

We are you using `CUPS` to send files to printers. Have a look on this example how to use `CUPS` with `php`
http://www.cups.org/articles.php?L545+TNews+Q

...but as @ROY Finley answered you need to know printers addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply configure profile recognition in Print&Share.
This video example uses a profile with a Printer Channel and one with a File Printer Channel:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvTly9qXQMI&list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2&index=38

You can easily create a profile with only Printer Channels, as you wish. This way you only have to print and the software will select the correct profile or A or B automatically (if you enable "Auto Send & Close" it will also print automatically without showing the user interface).